# List all files in a folder and sub folders into a table

Tags: r

Have a folder with sub folders and with various source code files withing those sub folders like .CSS, .java etc. Is it possible to list all these source code files into a table format with two columns(path and filename)

`all_files<-list.files(pattern = "*.*", recursive = TRUE)` is not working. I tried other functions like `lapply` cant seem to catch a break.

Comment: Welcome to SO and  job crafting and tweaking the question (you incrementally made it super clear what you're asking for which _really_ helps folks figure out possible answers). Having said that, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is `all_files` empty?

Comment: Thanks! When I use all_files<-list.files(pattern = "*.*", recursive = TRUE), the result is a single row with all the file names in a list. I want them in a column one below the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fils <- list.files("thedir", recursive = TRUE)

data.frame(
  path = dirname(fils),
  file = basename(fils),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```